# Integrate over a 512 dimensional cube

Tags: calculus, integration, approximate-integration

Basically, I'm trying to find what the mean and standard deviation of the distance between two random "hyperpoints" from a 512 dimensional hypercube of size 2 would be.

I was thinking the mean would be $\displaystyle{\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}...\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{(x_{1,1}-x_{1,2})^2+(x_{2,1}-x_{2,2})^2+(x_{3,1}-x_{3,2})^2+...+(x_{512,1}-x_{512,2})^2}}dx_{1,1}dx_{1,2}dx_{2,1}dx_{2,2}...dx_{512,1}dx_{512,2}$

A. Does that seem right?
B. If so, is there an analytic solution, and 
C. If not.. I estimated the mean as 18.4691104453 and the standard deviation as 0.483367889827 by simply choosing a million random 512 dimensional points in that range, and calculating a sample mean and sample standard deviation from that. Does that seem valid?

What I'd really like is a closed form solution for an n-dimensional hypercube...

Thanks!

Comment: (1) You should divide your integral by $2^{1024}$.  (2) The quantity in the square root is very nearly normally distributed, with mean $1024E(X-Y)^2$ and variance $1024(E(X-Y)^4-(E(X-Y)^2)^2$, where $X$ and $Y$ are iid uniform on $[-1,1]$.  The expectation of the square root of that quantity can  then be estimated by the "delta method".

Comment: The average value of samples will need to be multiplied by the volume of the cube to get the value of the integral.